# Is it possible to find out the amount of RAM in turbo pascal, and if so, how?

Tags: shell, dos, pascal, ram

**I need a program for dos**
Thanks in advance

I searched on the Internet but did not find anything for turbo pascal, only for pascal ABC

Comment: Read about DPMI and how to use it from your TP program. There’s a function _Get memory information_.